# Most elegant way to count integers in a list

Tags: python

I am looking for the most elegant way to do the following:

Let's say that I want to count number of times each integer appears in a list; I could do it this way:

```
x = [1,2,3,2,4,1,2,5,7,2]

dicto = {}

for num in x:
    try:
        dicto[num] = dicto[num] + 1
    except KeyError:
        dicto[num] = 1
```

However, I think that

```
try:
    dicto[num] = dicto[num] + 1
except KeyError:
    dicto[num] = 1
```

is not the most elegant ways to do it; I think that I saw the above code replaced by a single line. What is the most elegant way to do this?

I realized that this might be a repeat, but I looked around and couldn't find what I was looking for.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> x = [1,2,3,2,4,1,2,5,7,2]
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for i in x:
        d[i] += 1

>>> dict(d)
{1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 7: 1}
```

Or just [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), if you are on Python 2.7+.

Answer (score 8):

Use the Counter class

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> x = [1,2,3,2,4,1,2,5,7,2]
>>> c = Counter(x)
```

Now you can use the `Counter` object `c` as dictionary.

```
>>> c[1]
2
>>> c[10]
0
```

(This works for non-existant values too)

Comment: This is most correct if you'd like the additional overhead of the `Counter` class. Checking the source code, it is indeed backed by `dict`, making hashed lookup and iteration performance ideal.

Answer (score 1):

[Bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort), as you're doing, is entirely algorithmically appropriate ([discussion](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Initializing_Dictionary_Elements)). This seems ideal when you don't need the additional overhead from `Counter`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

wdict = defaultdict(int)

for word in words:
    wdict[word] += 1
```